# Dependent pattern matching on two values with the same type

Tags: pattern-matching, coq, dependent-type, convoy-pattern

We will use the standard definition of the finite sets:

```
Inductive fin : nat -> Set :=
| F1 : forall {n : nat}, fin (S n)
| FS : forall {n : nat}, fin n -> fin (S n).
```

Let us assume that we have some `P : forall {m : nat} (x y : fin m) : Set` (the
important thing is that both arguments of `P` are of the same type). For
demonstration purposes, let P be just:

```
Definition P {m : nat} (x y : fin m) := {x = y} + {x <> y}.
```

Now, we would like to write a custom function that compares two numbers:

```
Fixpoint feq_dec {m : nat} (x y : fin m) : P x y.
```

The idea is straightforward: we match on `x` and `y`, for `x = F1`, `y = F1` we
trivially return equality, for `x = FS x'`, `y = FS y'` we recursively call
the procedure for `x'` and `y'`, for other cases we can trivially return
inequality.

A direct translation of this idea into Coq obviously fails:

```
refine (
  match x, y return P x y with
  | F1 _, F1 _ => _
  | FS _ x', F1 _ => _
  | F1 _, FS _ y' => _
  | FS _ x', FS _ y' => _
  end
).

(*
 * The term "y0" has type "fin n0" while it is expected to have type "fin n".
 *)
```

During the match on `x` and `y` we loose the type information so we cannot apply them to `P`.
The standard trick with passing type equality proof does not help here:

```
refine (
  match x in fin mx, y in fin my return mx = my -> P x y with
  | F1 _, F1 _ => _
  | FS _ x', F1 _ => _
  | F1 _, FS _ y' => _
  | FS _ x', FS _ y' => _
  end eq_refl
).

(*
 * The term "y0" has type "fin my" while it is expected to have type "fin mx".
 *)
```

So, maybe we can use that proof of equality to cast `x` have the same type as
`y`?

```
Definition fcast {m1 m2 : nat} (Heq : m1 = m2) (x : fin m1) : fin m2.
Proof.
  rewrite <- Heq.
  apply x.
Defined.
```

We also need to be able to get rid of the cast later on. However, I noticed that
`fcast eq_refl x = x` is not sufficient as we need to make it work with
arbitrary equivalence proof. I have found something called UIP that does exactly
what I need.

```
Require Import Coq.Program.Program.

Lemma fcast_void {m : nat} : forall (x : fin m) (H : m = m),
  fcast H x = x.
Proof.
  intros.
  rewrite -> (UIP nat m m H eq_refl).
  trivial.
Defined.
```

Now we are ready to finish the whole definition:

```
refine (
  match x in fin mx, y in fin my
  return forall (Hmx : m = mx) (Hmy : mx = my), P (fcast Hmy x) y with
  | F1 _, F1 _ => fun Hmx Hmy => _
  | FS _ x', F1 _ => fun Hmx Hmy => _
  | F1 _, FS _ y' => fun Hmx Hmy => _
  | FS _ x', FS _ y' => fun Hmx Hmy => _
  end eq_refl eq_refl
); inversion Hmy; subst; rewrite fcast_void.
- left. reflexivity.
- right. intro Contra. inversion Contra.
- right. intro Contra. inversion Contra.
- destruct (feq_dec _ x' y') as [Heq | Hneq].
  + left. apply f_equal. apply Heq.
  + right. intro Contra. dependent destruction Contra. apply Hneq. reflexivity.
Defined.
```

It goes through! However, it doesn't evaluate to any useful value. For example
the following yields a term with five nested matches instead of a simple value
(`in_right` or `in_left`). I suspect the problem is with the UIP axiom that I
used.

```
Compute (@feq_dec 5 (FS F1) (FS F1)).
```

So in the end, the definition that I came up with is pretty much useless.
I have also tried doing nested matches using the *convoy pattern* instead of doing matching two values at
the same time but I hit the same obstacles: as soon as I do the matching on the second value, `P` stops being applicable to it. Can I do it some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the terms by hand but it's a nightmare. Here I describe the computational part and use tactics to deal with the proving:

```
Fixpoint feq_dec {m : nat} (x y : fin m) : P x y.
refine (
match m return forall (x y : fin m), P x y with
  | O    => _
  | S m' => fun x y =>
  match (case x, case y) with
    | (inright eqx            , inright eqy)             => left _
    | (inleft (exist _ x' eqx), inright eqy)             => right _
    | (inright eqx            , inleft (exist _ y' eqy)) => right _
    | (inleft (exist _ x' eqx), inleft (exist _ y' eqy)) =>
    match feq_dec _ x' y' with
      | left eqx'y'   => left _
      | right neqx'y' => right _
    end
  end
end x y); simpl in *; subst.
- inversion 0.
- reflexivity.
- intro Heq; apply neqx'y'.
  assert (Heq' : Some x' = Some y') by exact (f_equal finpred Heq).
  inversion Heq'; reflexivity.
- inversion 1.
- inversion 1.
- reflexivity.
Defined.
```

The function defined this way works as expected:

```
Compute (@feq_dec 5 (FS F1) (FS F1)).
(* 
 = left eq_refl
 : P (FS F1) (FS F1)
*)
```

This code relies on 3 tricks:

#### 1. Start by inspecting the bound `m`.

Indeed if you don't know anything about the bound `m`, you'll learn two different facts from the match on `x` and `y` respectively and you'll need to reconcile these facts (i.e. show that the two predecessor for `m` you're given are in fact equal). If, on the other hand, you know that `m` has the shape `S m'` then you can...

#### 2. Use a `case` function inverting the term based on the bound's shape

If you know that the bound has a shape `S m'` then you know for each one of your `fin`s that you are in one of two cases: either the `fin` is `F1` or it is `FS x'` for some `x'`. `case` makes this formal:

```
Definition C {m : nat} (x : fin (S m)) :=
  { x' | x = FS x' } + { x = F1 }.

Definition case {m : nat} (x : fin (S m)) : C x :=
match x in fin (S n) return { x' | x = FS x' } + { x = F1 } with
  | F1    => inright eq_refl
  | FS x' => inleft (exist _ x' eq_refl)
end.
```

Coq will be smart enough to detect that the values we are returning from `case` are direct subterms of the arguments it takes. So performing recursive calls when both `x` and `y` have the shape `FS _` won't be a problem!

#### 3. Use congruence with an ad-hoc function to peel off constructors

In the branch where we have performed a recursive call but got a negative answer in return, we need to prove `FS x' <> FS y'` knowing that `x' <> y'`. Which means that we need to turn `Heq : FS x' = FS y'` into `x' = y'`.

Because `FS` has a complicated return type, simply performing `inversion` on `Heq` won't yield a usable result (we get an equality between dependent pairs of a nat `p` and a `fin p`). This is were `finpred` comes into play: it's a total function which, when faced with `FS _` simply peels off the `FS` constructor.

```
Definition finpred {m : nat} (x : fin m) : option (fin (pred m)) :=
match x with
  | F1    => None
  | FS x' => Some x'
end.
```

Combined with `f_equal` and `Heq` we get a proof that `Some x' = Some y'` on which we can use `inversion` and get the equality we wanted.

Edit: I've put [all the code in a self-contained gist](https://gist.github.com/gallais/7b12caa45199431a3a1209142f6408db).

Comment: Awesome, works like a charm! The trick with inspecting an index first is something I need to remember. The part where Coq correctly detects `case`-ed values as subterms feels a little bit magical (especially considering how crippled the pattern matching mechanism is), but I am glad it works the way it does.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known problem and in most cases you are gonna fare better using the equality on the underlying `nat` and then taking profit than the `to_nat` function is injective:

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect.

Set Implicit Arguments.
Unset Strict Implicit.
Unset Printing Implicit Defensive.

Require Import PeanoNat Fin.

Fixpoint to_nat m (x : t m) :=
  match x with
  | F1 _   => 0
  | FS _ x => (to_nat x).+1
  end.

Lemma to_nat_inj m : injective (@to_nat m).
Proof.
elim: m / => /= [|m t iht y].
  exact: (caseS (fun n (y : t n.+1) => _)).
move: m y t iht.
by apply: (caseS (fun n (y : t n.+1) => _)) => //= n p t iht [] /iht ->.
Qed.

Lemma feq_dec {m : nat} (x y : t m) : {x = y} + {x <> y}.
Proof.
have [heq | heqN] := Nat.eq_dec (to_nat x) (to_nat y).
  by left; apply: to_nat_inj.
by right=> H; apply: heqN; rewrite H.
Qed.
```

But even so, things are still cumbersome to work with. You could try to use the `'I_n` type include in ssreflect which separates the computational value from the bound, a bit of search in SO should give you enough pointers.

If you turn the `Qed`s into `Defined` the above will compute for your case, and in general it should be enough to give you either `left ?` or `right ?` allowing proofs that depend on it to continue.

However it will need some large amount of tweaking if you want it to go throu a normal form in the non equal case [mainly, the `O_S` lemma being opaque, which also affects `Nat.eq_dec`]

Comment: Ah, `P` being a decision for equality was simply an example to demonstrate my typing problem. However, your trick with `nat` conversion is actually applicable to my real use case as well (but requires a lot of additional work). Thanks for pointing out this trick!

Comment: Maybe your use case would benefit then from the `SubType` class of math-comp.